# SP2013 - Sporadic issues with opening documents

Tags: 2013, document-library

We have a few users that are having sporadic issues when trying to open up Office documents. They click on the document, the splash screen for Word/Excel/PowerPoint shows up, and get this message

> We're having trouble connecting to the server. If this keeps
>   happening, contact your help desk.

This has happened to both in-house and remote employees (on VPN), on both wired and wireless connections. I'm not sure if file size plays a part in this, but I've seen some PPTX files which were about 100mb. I have never seen this issue on my machine in all the scenarios listed above though.

Any ideas?